# Swap order of quaternion multiplication

Tags: quaternions

I have three quaternions, *A, B and C* such that *A = B* * *C*.

I would like to be able to swap the order of *B* and *C* so that *A = C* * *B* but of course quaternions aren't commutitive so just swapping the order results in a different value for *A*.

Is there a way to transform B so that after the swap *A = C* * *B'* is true? I would prefer a transform that just uses *B*, but if need be I can settle for a transform that would also uses *A* or *C*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive a formula by setting up the equality $$B\cdot C=A=C\cdot B'$$ From here, it is clear that if we take the inverse of C on the left side of each equation, we obtain a formula for B' $$B'=C^{-1}\cdot B\cdot C$$

Comment: Not only is this formula always true (as long as $C$ has an inverse), you can use it to easily find examples in which you start always with a given value of $B,$ but depending on your choice of $C$ you get different values of $B'$, thereby proving that there is no way to derive $B'$ from $B$ alone.

Answer (score 1):

> $B'=C^{-1}\cdot B\cdot C$

In addition to @Tyberius answer, the geographic meaning of $B'$ is actually representing the rotation operation of $B$ back in coordinates before $C$ rotation has occurred.

In another word, $B\cdot C$ means apply $B$ then in the resultant coordinates apply $C$ rotation, while $C\cdot B$ means apply $B$ then in the **original** coordinates apply $C$ rotation.